# llvm caller saved registers not reloaded after function call

Tags: llvm, riscv, register-allocation

I am generating code with a customized RISCV backend for llvm. When I compile with no optimization (-O0) the program is functional. When I compile with optimization (-O2), none of the temporary registers (caller saved) are being reloaded after calls. The optimized code does appear to have a good register allocation but it does things like loading a temporary register with the address of a class initializer and then calling the initializer several times without reloading the register.

```
load t1 %(foo)
jal t1
...
jal t1
...
jal t1
```

The .bc file looks basically the same as this pseudo-code, correctly declaring the live ranges (lifetime.start and lifetime.end) to span all of the function calls.

I think the strategy of the register allocator is to use the caller saved registers first, so I don't think this is an issue of incorrectly declaring my registers. In the older register allocators, I see where loadRegFromStackSlot() or assignVirt2StackSlot() functions are used to spill the registers requiring reloading after being clobbered. But in the greedy register allocator I don't see an obvious place where this occurs, so I don't know how to debug what my backend might be missing.

Perhaps I need to add another pass or a different pass to the code generator. Perhaps I have something wrong with my register declarations, but I don't think so. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using riscv/riscv-llvm from GitHub you may need to grab the following fix. I was seeing similar issues without it.

https://github.com/riscv/riscv-llvm/commit/ce8ac4e3ed8956a37bf330ee4a431c6fdfabac37

The following issue report indicates similar problems and one of the answers points to the above change:

https://github.com/riscv/riscv-llvm/issues/32

Comment: Thanks Mike, you are correct. I figured these changes out myself late last week - the hard way!